# pass ko observable to jade mixin as parameter

Tags: knockout.js, pug, mixins

I have a question: is there any way to pass ko.observable(); variable to jade mixin.
For example code:

```
var obs = ko.observable('text');
```

and example mixin:

```
mixin myMixin(textToBind)
 span(data-bind="text: '#{textToBind}'")
```

call of mixin:

```
+myMixin(obs)
```

but in output text is unavailable, displays just empty block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this type of method work for you?

```
mixin myMixin(textToBind)
 span(data-bind="text: "+textToBind)
```

then to use it

```
+myMixin("fullName")
```

See https://codepen.io/cwg999/pen/wXryRv

Comment: my way was similar to your answer, so I accepted it